# how we set label Constraints in uitableview cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I want to set a Label Constraints in a tableview cell. 
When I'm setting a Label Constraint and run on a device then auto layout not work on different device like iPhone 5,6 and iPhone 7 plus.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV6o1.jpg)

How to set the auto layout constraints to get the layout working fine for all the devices?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by not working  ?  Put some tried code and outcome

Comment: Use proportional values for all constraints (leading, trailing, top, bottom)

Comment: When application run on small device then uilabel width not set according to the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This -

Drag a Label into cell.
Suppose you want to have margin of 10 pixels from each side of label. Set a constant of 10 for all (top, bottom, leading, trailing) and click on Add 4 constraints. as in below image

[image]

Now, If you have only problem with width of label then do the following -

in `viewWillAppear` Method

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50.0;
```

And then use following method -

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

     return  UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

And you problem should be solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide estimated row height for the cell or set it to automatic.

Example:-

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

or by like this:-

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
 return 240
}
```

Comment: Not a Height problem, when application run on small device then label width not set according to the screen

Comment: You have to provide constraints for tableView with the respective view.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set following params

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140.0; //some values according to the your requirement
```